# Retornar JSON para PHP

Tags: php, ajax, json

Estou fazendo um sistema de cadastro, onde a busca do CEP deverá aparecer assim que muda o campo. Mas o retorno do AJAX não está funcionando. 
Como fazer o retorno do JSON para o PHP?
PS: a busca de CEP é offline

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
   $("#cep").change(function(){
      var cep = $(this).val();
      if( cep.length <= 0 ) return;
      $.getJSON('cep.ajax.php',{cep: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'}, function(result) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(result));
            $("input#cep").val( result.cep );
            $("input#estado").val( result.uf );
            $("input#cidade").val( result.cidade );
            $("input#bairro").val( result.bairro );
            $("input#endereco").val( result.rua );
            $("input#estado").val( result.uf );
               });
            });
         });

</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>CEP:</label><input type="text" name="cep" id="cep" /><br />
<label>Bairro:</label><input type="text" name="bairro" id="bairro" /><br />
<label>Endereço:</label><input type="text" name="endereco" id="endereco" /><br />
<label>Número:</label><input type="text" name="numero" id="numero" /><br />
<label>Complemento:</label><input type="text" name="complemento" id="complemento" /><br />
<label>Cidade:</label><input type="text" name="cidade" id="cidade" /><br />
<label>Estado:</label><input type="text" name="estado" id="estado" /><br />


//arquivo cep.ajax.php
<?php

 $cep = mysqli_real_escape_string($concep, $_REQUEST['cep'] );
    $cep5 = substr($cep,0,5);


    //define tabela
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM cep_log_index WHERE cep5='$cep5'";
 $res = mysqli_query($concep, $sql );
 while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $res ) ) {
      $uf = $row['uf'];
 }
 
 //busca cep
 $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM $uf WHERE cep='$cep'";
 $res2 = mysqli_query($concep, $sql2 );
 while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $res2 ) ) {
      $tipo = $row['tp_logradouro'];
            $rua  =  $row['logradouro'];
            $bairro =  $row['bairro'];
            $cidade =  $row['cidade'];
            $cep = $row['cep'];
 };

$endereco = array("tipo"=>$tipo, "rua"=>$rua, "bairro"=>$bairro, "cidade"=>$cidade, "cep"=>$cep, "uf"=>$uf);

echo json_encode($endereco);

?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Descobri o problema.
Não ecoava devido à acentuação.
Foi somente colocar a codificação como abaixo no arquivo `cep.ajax.php` e o problema foi resolvido!

```
$cidade = (utf8_encode($row['cidade']));
```

Answer (score 0):

Adiciona o `header` `Content-Type`

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($endereco);
```

Comment: Acredito q não seja este o problema, trabalho sem o header e os dados são trazidos normalmente.

Comment: Ele chega a chamar a requisição ajax?

Comment: tentei usar o cod: "alert(JSON.stringify(result));", para verificar se está indo a variável, mas nada..então, não sei se ele chama a requisição.

Comment: Verifica se no console aparece algum erro e se esta indo a requisição

Comment: Coloquei o header, e nisso consigo ver a página cep.ajax.php está ok. No console não mostra erro, e descobri que se coloco o CEP sem o '-', ao menos agora me ecoa o retorno, tudo em 'null'.